# postfix problems with pattern in virtual file

Tags: postfix

We are trying to forward all emails to a specific email address. I think everything is set up okay, such as 'main.cf' and 'virtual-regexp' files. If we put the following in the 'virtual' file, the forwarding works correctly:

`@example.com mainid@example.com`

However, if we try to use the following in 'virtual' to send ALL email to the ID, it ignores it and sends it to the original user:

`(.*) mainid@example.com`

We got the idea for the above from the following [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270439/postfix-2-9-6-1-forward-all-mail-to-an-external-mail-address).

Any ideas why the pattern '(.*)' doesn't work? We've tried so many different patterns that our heads are starting to spin.

Comment: Did you ever read the question you have linked?

It is stated their that (.*) is not working and you need to use virtual-regexp with /.+@.+/ in it.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the question/answer, why are you using `(.*)` as the expression?

The answer marked correct to the question you link to clearly uses the regex expression:

`/.+@.+/`

edit: if you, for whatever reason, do not want to actually read the answer in your link, I'll copy/paste it here for you.

> Finally found the answer.
>
> Listing here for posterity.
>
> Add the folowing line to the end of your main.cf file
>
> ```
> vi /etc/postfix/main.cf
> virtual_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual, regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp
> ```
>
> Create a file which lists the mail
>   address you want all mails to be sent to
>
> ```
> vi /etc/postfix/virtual-regexp
> ```
>
> Add the following:
>
> ```
> /.+@.+/ forwarding mailaddress@gmail.com
> ```
>
> add it to postmap
>
> ```
> postmap /etc/postfix/virtual-regexp
> ```
>
> you will need to add a virtual file.
>
> ```
> touch /etc/postfix/virtual
> ```
>
> now add it to postmap
>
> ```
> postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
> ```

Comment: I have the virtual-regexp file set up that way.  Let me explain further.

Comment: Your questions specifically says "However, if we try to use the following in 'virtual' to send ALL email to the ID, it ignores it and sends it to the original user:

(.*) mainid@example.com" then goes on to ask "Any ideas why the pattern '(.*)' doesn't work?". If you're asking why (.*) doesn't work when the answer says to use `/.+@.+/`, in what way have you setup the file the way the answer said to?

Comment: I have the virtual-exp file set up that way.  Let me explain further.

virtual-exp has the regular expression listed.
virtual has the (.*) suggested.

If I comment out the line in virtual and use, for example, the explicit "@example.com mainid@example.com", it works:

virtual:
#(.*) mainid@example.com
@example.com mainid@example.com
virtual-regexp:
/.+@.+/ mainid@example.com


If I try the expression in virtual, then it does not work.

virtual:
(.*) mainid@example.com
#@example.com mainid@example.com
virtual-regexp:
/.+@.+/ mainid@example.com


This tells me that there is something with (.*)

Comment: I also tried to put the same regular expression (plus every other combination we think could of, with and without slashes) in virtual with no success.
The original article only suggests the (.*) for virtual.

Comment: One other comment.  I tried to do this with no value set in the virtual file.  That does not work also.  Something needs to be set in that file as well that works in conjunction with the virtual-regexp file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

You need to complete the steps listed above.  But, in addition, you need to comment out the following lines in main.cf (if they are there) before restarting the postfix process:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```